# OpenSSL error while Building PCL on windows

Tags: openssl, conda, point-cloud-library, build-error, vcpkg

I am new to GIS. I am trying to build PCL on windows(MS visual studio 2017) using VCPKG manager using the command: vcpkg install pcl:x64-windows. Build is failing with the following OpenSSL error:

```
Building package openssl-windows[core]:x64-windows...
-- Downloading http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.24.1.1/strawberry-perl- 
5.24.1.1-32bit-portable.zip...
-- Downloading http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.24.1.1/strawberry-perl- 
5.24.1.1-32bit-portable.zip... Failed. Status: 22;"HTTP response code said 
error"
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_download_distfile.cmake:156 (message):

  Failed to download file.
  If you use a proxy, please set the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment
  variables to "https://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
  Otherwise, please submit an issue at 
  https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_find_acquire_program.cmake:237 
  (vcpkg_download_distfile)
  ports/openssl-windows/portfile.cmake:9 (vcpkg_find_acquire_program)
  scripts/ports.cmake:71 (include)


  Error: Building package openssl-windows:x64-windows failed with: 
  BUILD_FAILED
  Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, 
  then
  submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: openssl-windows:x64-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2018.10.20-nohash
```

Looks like the URL is not working.
Alternatively, I tried to install PCL using conda package manager. It installed properly but can I link an external application to the PCL Libraries? If so how to do that? Where do I find the headers and libraries? I am also not able to run applications like pclviewer pcl_visualizer etc.,

Please suggest if there is any alternate way to build PCL from source?
Thanks!

Comment: At least now the URL works. Did you try if it works or is your internet access blocked?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..As you said it is the internet access at work which is blocking. Works with home network. It took almost 5 hours for PCL to build on windows.